# How can I make a toggle to toggle the visibility of an inline SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm making a website where you can create your own character in order to learn more about SVGs. I want the user to be able to select different poses.

I was wondering how I could toggle the visibility of an SVG on the website to make one disappear and another appear.

Here is my SVG code:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 720 720" style="enable-background:new 0 0 720 720;" xml:space="preserve">  
  <g id="skin">
    <circle class="skin" cx="364.42" cy="383" r="278" />
  </g>
  <g id="mouth">
    <path class="mouth" d="M172.92,383c127.67,0,255.33,0,383,0c0,105.05-86.45,191.5-191.5,191.5S172.92,488.05,172.92,383z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="hair">
    <path class = "hair" d="M107.4,276.86c-2.76-50.59,10.76-81.24,24.2-100.13C189.57,95.31,331.92,112,341.92,57.91
      c2.04-11.03-2.07-21.46-6.93-29.61c18.47-6.31,81.92-25.39,151.28,3.28c94.59,39.09,121.88,137.21,127.56,160.84
      c7.93,32.98,7.18,61.32,5.46,79.42c-38.79-64.73-78.17-85.57-107.42-92.42c-43.32-10.15-60.72,11.26-139.64,11.71
      c-67.77,0.39-78.13-15.27-119.49-10.14C216.75,185.45,165.19,204.69,107.4,276.86z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="eyes">
    <g>
      <circle class = "eyes" cx="251.17" cy="271.25" r="52.4"/>
      <circle class = "eyes" cx="477.67" cy="271.25" r="52.4"/>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g id="clothing">
    <rect x="236.92" y="644.4" width="255" height="180"/>
  </g>
  <g id="tie">
    <rect class="tie" x="341.82" y="653.68" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 584.9371 -59.6038)" class="st0" width="45.2" height="45.2"/>
    <path class="tie" d="M364.95,927.93c-6.29-12.71-12.59-25.42-18.88-38.13c3.44-63.19,6.89-126.39,10.33-189.58
      c5.1,0.25,10.2,0.49,15.29,0.74c4.13,62.75,8.25,125.49,12.38,188.24C377.7,902.11,371.32,915.02,364.95,927.93z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The SVG is just a sample right now before I make the actual assets.

Comment: set the element to visibility: hidden or display:none

Comment: if you want to use a button or toggle the visibility on an event, check out the jQuery toggleClass method: https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/